# How to call Azure CLI functions from Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, botframework

I am trying to create an Ansible playbook for the bot framework. From the looks of it the REST API cant be used to create the bots but it is available from the Azure CLI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tools-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-3.0 .

Is there a way to call Azure CLI functions from Ansible since the create resource module wont be able to handle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Ansible [`shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html) module to invoke Azure CLI and other commands as if you're working from the the command line, then capture the output in Ansible for downstream use in the playbook.

I don't work with Azure, but I do with AWS. Here's an example using AWS CLI inside of Ansible and capturing the output for use in the next task.

```
---
- name: Create / Delete IAM user with keys
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:
    username: foo

  tasks:
    - name: Create user with keys
      iam:
        iam_type: user
        name: "{{ username }}"
        state: present
        access_key_state: create
        key_count: 2

    - name: Get all the access keys
      shell: aws iam list-access-keys --user-name {{ username }} --query 'AccessKeyMetadata[*].AccessKeyId'
      register: access_key_list

    - name: Delete each key
      shell: aws iam delete-access-key --access-key-id {{ item }} --user-name {{ username }}
      loop: "{{ access_key_list.stdout | from_json }}"

    - name: Delete user
      iam_user:
        name: "{{ username }}"
        state: absent
```

Notice on the second task, we are registering the command output in a variable `access_key_list`. You can then convert the contents of that variable to JSON and work with it in later tasks.

Since command output comes in all forms, you can use the [`debug`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html) module to peek at the variable so you can decide how to handle it.

```
- name: Output variable contents
  debug:
    msg: "{{ access_key_list }}"
```

Answer (score 5):

Since comments do not support formatting, here is the tip:

I use `>` like this to make it more readable.

```
---
- name: RENAME {{ DB_DATABASE_NAME }} DATABASE on {{ DB_SRC_SQLSERVER_NAME }} SQLSERVER to {{ DB_DATABASE_NEW_NAME }} DATABASE
  command: >
     az sql db rename
     --resource-group "{{ DB_RESOURCEGROUP_NAME }}"
     --server "{{ DB_SQLSERVER_NAME }}"
     --name "{{ DB_DATABASE_NAME }}"
     --new-name "{{ DB_DATABASE_NEW_NAME }}"
```

Check documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html

Comment: see https://yaml-multiline.info/ for more tips and tricks on multiline YAML